# Unable to create SPUserToken objects or use SPSecurity class

Tags: development, 2013, library

[image]

As shown in this image, I am unable to create a SPUserToken or run the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges() delegate in order to elevate the current user for the purpose of managing list item permissions. Is there a different Microsoft.Sharepoint library that I should be using, or something silly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you've selected the default of creating a "Sandboxed solution" in which `SPUserToken` and `SPSecurity` isn't supported.

If you need to run elevated, then your solution should be a Farm solution (or and app with AllowAppOnlyPolicy).

Click the SharePoint project node ('DOCApp') and check the properties (F4):
[image]

This should be set to `False` to allow running elevated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changed to False and now it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with complete code for `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` or `SPUserToken` code? It seems that you have correctly referred the `Microsoft.SharePoint` (in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll) assembly in source code.

Try an example below with `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){  


         using (SPSite newSite = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl)) {  

            using (SPWeb newWeb = newSite.OpenWeb()){
               //some logic

          }// End of using for SPWeb

       }// End of Using for SPSite

   });//End of SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges
```